# How to get all files of a certain type from a virtual web path?

Tags: python, wget, curl

I try to use `wget` to download certain files from a website. But probably the virtual locations of the files do not represent their actual location.

For example, if the link to the file is `http://file.site.com/1746534/relativity_theory_explained.txt`, it does not mean that there is a real folder `http://file.site.com/`, or `http://file.site.com/1746534/` and/or that `relativity_theory_explained.txt` is in that folder.
Actually, when I access `http://file.site.com/` from the browser I get HTTP 403, so I am not sure.

If I access exactly `http://file.site.com/1746534/relativity_theory_explained.txt` from the browser, I can see the file.
However, I have no way to guess what the names of the files I want to download may be, other than the fact that their paths have the pattern `http://file.site.com/some_number/some_name.txt`

Is there a way to use bash or python to download these files, which all I know about is the beginning of their path?

Here is what I tried:

```
wget \
 --recursive \
 --no-clobber \
 --convert-links \
 --restrict-file-names=windows \
 --domains site.com \
 -e robots=off \
 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0' \
 --accept "*.txt" \
 --accept "*.html" \
 --no-parent \
     www.site.com file.site.com
```

The html files (www.site.com/...) that contain the links are downloaded. The files to which the links point (file.site.com/...) are not downloaded. Strictly `file.site.com` in the browser takes me to 403. The parameters I use are `--domains site.com --accept ".txt" --accept ".html" www.site.com file.site.com`

I am interested in the txt files, not html, but I download also the htmls in order to grab the links.

Comment: `Is there a way to use bash or python to download these files, which all I know about is the beginning of their path?` This is basically the same question as "Is there a way to visit someone's house, when all I know about is which planet they live on?"

Comment: `Also, those files that I want to download, do have some chain of links pointing to them from the main page` This, however, is what `wget`'s mirror features deal with. `but for some reason wget do not get them.` – so then, what reason? What happens when you try?

Comment: @Michael Homer the html files (www.site.com/...) that contain the links are downloaded. The files to which the links point (file.site.com/...) are not downloaded. Strictly `file.site.com` takes me to 403. The parameters I use are ` --domains site.com --accept "*.txt" --accept "*.html" www.site.com file.site.com` I am interested in the txt files, not html, but I download also the htmls in order to grab the links.

Comment: You can [edit] your post with (as near as possible) *actual commands and their results*. Please make sure that they are representative; what you have in that comment and what you have in the question don't match.